# how do you add additional nics to a compute engine vm?

Tags: google-compute-engine, nic

how do I add a NIC to a compute engine instance? I need more then one NIC so I can build out an environment...I've looked all over and there is nothing on how to do it...

I know it's probably some API call through the SDK, but I have no idea, and I can't find anything on it.

EDIT:
It's the rhel6 image. figured I should clarify.

Answer (score 2):

The question is probably old and a lot has changed since. Now it's definitely possible to add more nics to an instance but only at creation time (you can find a networking tab on the create instance page on the portal - corresponding rest api exists too). Each nic has to connect to a different virtual network, so you need to create more before creating the instance (if you don't have already).

Answer (score 1):

Do you need an external address or an internal address?  If external, you can use [gcutil to add an IP address](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#ipassign) to an existing instance.  If internal, you can [configure a static network address](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#staticnetworkaddress) on the instance, and add a [route entry](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking#routing) to send traffic for that address to that instance.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for similiar thing (to have a VM which runs Apache and nginx simultaneously on different IPs), but it seems like although you can have multiple networks (up to 5) in a project and each network can belong to multiple instances, you can not have more than one network per instance. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking#networks):

> A project can contain multiple networks and each network can have multiple instances attached to it. [...] A network belongs to only one project and each instance can only belong to one network.